# docker-compose --env-file unknown flag

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Today I updated Docker (Docker for Mac) to 4.22.0

When I try to execute

```
docker-compose up --env-file .env.local
```

I get

```
unknown flag: --env-file
```

I could make it work if I create a new file `.env`, but is there a way to pass the env file as an argument of `docker-compose`?

Comment: You need to put your `up` command after you specified the `--env-file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/) you should specify it with the command:

```
 docker compose --env-file .env.local up
```

The file path is relative to the current working directory where the Docker Compose command is executed.